# .jar file is not opening on 10.15.7 macOS Catalina

Tags: mac, error, java

**I have a JAR file, which is a program. I want to open this file, but when I double click the icon flashes for half-a-second but then nothing happens.
I tried to open via `java -jar Downloads/launcher.jar`, which returns this:**

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class cr.riselauncher.Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "/m/Dispatcher️" in class file 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
```

So, I didn't understand a lot from here, but, is it a code error, or is it because of my computer, I have the latest Java, the code is specified for a mac, maybe one of the files in the JAR is missing (cr.riselauncher.Launcher)?

*MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012), macOS Catalina 10.15.7*

*The recommended version of Java, Java 8 Update 281, 1.8.0_281*

*Only one Java installed on my Mac, not more*

Comment: Try running it with Java 11 instead: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-11-lts&os=macos&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk

Comment: Is the jar file corrupted?